AWS EKS pod is unable to ping external IP
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ping-pod
  namespace: besu
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox:latest
    command:
      - sh
      - -c
      - "ping -c 5 google.com"
  restartPolicy: Never


[![Pod logs after execution][1]]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/RM5UN.png

Whats your vpc setup to provide internet access to pods? Nat Gateway?

yes it is nat gateway

Could you check using VPC flow logs on whether these are forwarded or REJECT. Security Group Egress also needs check.

vpc flow logs helped me identify the eni associated with the VPC, thereby after adding the outbound rule to security group, the pod is able to ping external url. thankyou @Halod
